# Can't create a new android project after updating eclipse and download Android 4.3 (API 18)

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated and downloaded eclipse and `Android 4.3 (API 18)` and after that whenever I try to create a new project there is not any option in the "`compile with`" part and also when I try to run previously created application I get an error like 
"An internal error occurred during: "`Launching theanilpaudel`"-:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```